# REACT - sharing data between siblings causes main app to re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

First of all, I'm learning react and never post anything here.
Sorry if I sound confusing, cuz I really am...

I have the following project using **Functional Components**:

```
APP(Parent)
    |---- Header (child)
            |---- Favorites (grandchild - shows total of favorites)
  
    |---- ListGames (child)
            |---- Card
                    |----ButtonSendFavorites (grandchild)
  
    |---- Fotter (child)
```

These components are individual files. I used useState/Lifting State Up
to send the selected game from my ListGames to Favorites(grandchild).
Worked as intend, also as not intend, all my app re-renders. Took me
few minutes to realise what happened (lifting state up to parent and
changing it will cause a re-render, duhhhh). So... is there a way to
send the selected game to Favorites (grandChild) without re-render APP
and all of his children?

I tried useCallBack but as I said, I'm learning and in that point
everything started to mix up. I even asked help to chatGPT but it's
answer doesn't worked as well. So, is there a way to do it without
advanced state management?! I hope that I made myself clear.
Thanks anyways.

Comment: If you don't rerender then how will you show the state updates?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your question/answer. So I was wondering if is it possible to re-render  the intended component, in this case, only Favorites has changed. Everytime I select a favorite, my whole app re-renders, even Footer.

Comment: That's because the state is kept in the root.